# Laravel - Redirect users back to another form with all data intact, on clicking Previous button

Tags: laravel

I have two forms as below

**Form 1**

```
<form id="form1" action="loc1" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleDOB">Date of Brth:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dob" name="dob" placeholder="Date of Birth" 
         value="{{$tuser->DOB ??  ''}}" >
                <div class="error text-danger"></div>
 </div>


<button type="submit">Next Step</button><br><br>
<a href="{{url()->previous()}}"><button type="button">Previous </button></a>
</form>
```

**Form 2**

```
<form id="form2" action="loc2" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleMob">Mobile Number:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobno" name="mobno" placeholder="Valid Mobile 
                    Number" value="{{$tuser->mobno ??  ''}}" >
                <div class="error text-danger"></div>
 </div>

<button type="submit">Final Step</button><br><br>
<a href="{{url()->previous()}}"><button type="button">Previous </button></a>
</form>
```

`$tuser` is an object containing all the data for that user, from the database

When users click on `Next Step` in Form 1, the data is stored in database and the user is directed to Form 2.

But the problem is- on clicking the `Previous` button, I am **losing all the pre-filled data** in the **Previous *form***. How can I retain form data (to be shown in the input fields as available in the database)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have saved them in DB, so you can retrieve all of it using an id and store it in session like:

```
session->put("form_1_id",$DBInsertedId);
```

in form 1 you can check if there are any results, you can retrieve it like:

```
if(session->has("form_1_id"))
    return view('form_1',['filled_data' => Model::find(session->get("form_1_id")) ]);
```

and in the view you can check for parameter existence **form_1_id** like you did:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="dob" name="dob" placeholder="Date of Birth" 
     value="{{$filled_data->DOB ??  ''}}" >
```

just add a filled name id in your input view and fill it if form has been filled out before. since doing this can assure you that the filled form will be updated if there was a record for it before:

```
<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="{{$filled_data->id ??  ''}}" >
```

and in your controller:

```
Model::insertOrUpdate(['id' => $request->id ], ... );
```

### UPDATE:

insertOrUpdate Equivalent in psudo-code :

```
if(DB::exist(['id' => $request->id]))
    update(['id' => $request->id , ... ]);
else
    insert([ ... ]);
```

Comment: Our company does not use `Laravel Model`. Can you suggest alternatives?

Comment: and is there any problem if I dont use `session` , rather use the Controller to retrieve data from database and send it to previous form?

Comment: if you dosent use Elequent Model, How you insert data in DB?

Comment: Using Stored Procedures

Comment: you have to have a pointer to know which form-data has been saved in database. since http is stateless, we have to track user. tracking mechanism is this fashion are **hidden input tracking**, **cookie tracking**, **session tracking**. and session is the easiest among them to implement

Comment: so if there is a store procedure for this (create or update), its better to use it. but if there aint any, you can first check of row existance and if there isnt any you can try to create it, if there was any you have to update the db. ill append this to answer.

Comment: I am trying with the `session`. Seems easier and shorter to me